# How is sin$(7θ)−$sin$(θ)=$sin$(3θ)$ where $θ∈[0,π]$ solved?

Tags: trigonometry

I cannot seem to apply the method I have used to solve the previous question to solve this one (image is below).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e27GW.png

sin$(7θ)−$sin$(θ)=$sin$(3θ)$ where $ θ ∈ [0,π]$

Is there any other way I can do this (preferably using trig identities so I can understand)?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: start with $\sin(7\theta)-\sin(\theta)=\sin(4\theta+3\theta)-\sin(4\theta-3\theta)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By applying the formula

$$
\sin(x)-\sin(y) = 2\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right),
$$

we get

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sin(7\theta)-\sin(\theta) = \sin(3\theta) &\Leftrightarrow \\
2\sin\left(\frac{7\theta-\theta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{7\theta+\theta}{2}\right) - \sin(3\theta) = 0 & \Leftrightarrow \\
2\sin(3\theta)\cos(4\theta)-\sin(3\theta) = 0 &\Leftrightarrow \\
\sin(3\theta)\left(2\cos(4\theta)-1\right) = 0 &\Leftrightarrow \\
\ldots
\end{aligned}
$$

Could you continue further?

Comment: Thanks, I can continue from here!